# Installing gluonnlp results in an ImportError undefined symbol _PyGen_Send

Tags: python, pip, cython, gluon, mxnet

I hope this is not an incredibly dumb issue, but googling did not produce any useable results.
I installed `gluonnlp 0.10.0` using `pip` on a Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS server under Python 3.10.6.
When I try to import gluon, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3460, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-e68c3b59001c>", line 1, in <module>
    import gluonnlp as nlp
  File "[...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonnlp/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import data
  File "[...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonnlp/data/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import (batchify, candidate_sampler, conll, corpora, dataloader,
  File "[...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonnlp/data/corpora/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import (google_billion_word, large_text_compression_benchmark, wikitext)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonnlp/data/corpora/google_billion_word.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ...vocab import Vocab
  File "[...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonnlp/vocab/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import bert, elmo, subwords, vocab
  File "[...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonnlp/vocab/bert.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..data.transforms import SentencepieceTokenizer
  File "[...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonnlp/data/transforms.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .fast_bert_tokenizer import is_control, is_punctuation, is_whitespace
ImportError: [...]/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gluonnlp/data/fast_bert_tokenizer.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyGen_Send
```

`pip list` returns the following modules, if this information is helpfull:

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ -----------
asttokens                2.2.1
backcall                 0.2.0
certifi                  2022.12.7
charset-normalizer       3.0.1
click                    8.1.3
contourpy                1.0.7
cvxpy                    1.3.0
cycler                   0.11.0
Cython                   0.29.33
decorator                5.1.1
ecos                     2.0.12
executing                1.2.0
fasttext                 0.9.2
filelock                 3.9.0
fonttools                4.38.0
fst-pso                  1.8.1
FuzzyTM                  2.0.5
gensim                   4.3.0
germansentiment          1.1.0
gluonnlp                 0.10.0
graphviz                 0.8.4
h5py                     3.8.0
hdbscan                  0.8.29
huggingface-hub          0.12.1
idna                     3.4
ipython                  8.10.0
jedi                     0.18.2
joblib                   1.2.0
kaleido                  0.2.1
kiwisolver               1.4.4
llvmlite                 0.39.1
matplotlib               3.7.0
matplotlib-inline        0.1.6
miniful                  0.0.6
mxnet                    1.9.1
nltk                     3.8.1
numba                    0.56.4
numpy                    1.23.5
nvidia-cublas-cu11       11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11   11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11        8.5.0.96
osqp                     0.6.2.post8
packaging                23.0
pandas                   1.5.3
parso                    0.8.3
pexpect                  4.8.0
pickleshare              0.7.5
Pillow                   9.4.0
pip                      23.0.1
plotly                   5.13.0
polars                   0.16.7
prompt-toolkit           3.0.36
ptyprocess               0.7.0
pure-eval                0.2.2
pybind11                 2.10.3
pyFUME                   0.2.25
Pygments                 2.14.0
pynndescent              0.5.8
pyparsing                3.0.9
pyportfolioopt           1.5.4
python-dateutil          2.8.2
pytz                     2022.7.1
PyYAML                   6.0
qdldl                    0.1.5.post3
regex                    2022.10.31
requests                 2.28.2
scikit-learn             1.2.1
scipy                    1.10.1
scs                      3.2.2
sentence-transformers    2.2.2
sentencepiece            0.1.97
setuptools               64.0.2
simpful                  2.9.0
simple-elmo              0.9.1
six                      1.16.0
sklearn                  0.0.post1
smart-open               6.3.0
Snowball                 0.5.2
stack-data               0.6.2
tenacity                 8.2.1
threadpoolctl            3.1.0
tokenizers               0.13.2
top2vec                  1.0.28
torch                    1.13.1
torchvision              0.14.1
tqdm                     4.64.1
traitlets                5.9.0
transformers             4.26.1
typing                   3.6.6
typing_extensions        4.5.0
umap-learn               0.5.3
urllib3                  1.26.14
wcwidth                  0.2.6
wheel                    0.38.4
wordcloud                1.8.2.2
```

I tried reinstalling `cython`, `gluonnlp` and `mxnet` and would like to avoid using another python version if possible. The [documentation](https://nlp.gluon.ai/install/install-more.html) at least states that `python 3.5+` should be supported.
I would be gratefull for any pointer you might have!

##### Edit

I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/dmlc/gluon-nlp/issues/1595) describing my problem in the gluon gihub repo.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the maintainer at gluon and not StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I opened an issue in the github. Since the issues there seem to have less activity, I would be gratefull for any pointer here.

Comment: Link the issue in your question please.

Comment: Of course, sorry!

Comment: I think you might just need to force a rebuild with Cython. Possibly just `pip ... --install-option=--force`

Comment: This unforunately did not solve my issue, removing and reinstalling with the force-flag  cython and gluon did not fix the issue.
Thank you for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your python version (3.10 -> 3.8.16)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).